# Direct3D: Vertex color component vs. IDirect3DDevice9::SetMaterial

Tags: 3d, directx, direct3d

What are the differences between the two approaches to coloring my Direct3D model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you do it via a material then the whole Draw(Indexed)Primitive call will provide you with a single colour in the lighting equation (ie the one set in set material).

If you set it as a per-vertex colour then each vertex can have a different colour AND each colour will be interpolated across the polygon.

Of course bear in mind that you have different colours that can come from per-vertex and material (ie Emissive, Ambient, Diffuse and Specular).  To truly understand what it is doing under the hood I recommend you read the [article on the mathematics of lighting in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147178(VS.85).aspx).